# Getting viewport pixel offset

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the number of pixels from the top of the document at the top of the window viewport? For example, if I scroll half way down a page how can I find how many pixel that is from the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the jquery native "scroll" and "scrollTop" functions?

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        // log pixels scrolled to the console
        console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Pure JS Example (without jQuery):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping for a pure JS answer but since that does the job I think I'll just take that

Comment: Huh... just tried youre pure JS version and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: no kidding? hm... I've just pasted it into a blank document and it's working for me. are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: that's very odd -- i would just use the jquery implementation then as it's possible you're running into some browser compatibility issues. if you post you're code by editing your original post I can take a closer look1

Comment: that's very odd. you may want to use the jquery implementation as it's possible that you're running into some browser compatibility issues.

if you edit your original post and add your code to it i can take a closer look!